# missing line breaks

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to include a fb feed on a website using the graph api
ie. https://graph.facebook.com/xxx?fields=feed

This works fine but I noticed when looping through the objects that the actual content is missing layout formatting, especially line breaks. This makes the content of the returned strings rather unusefull for me right now.

Is there another way of retrieving the formatted text, or am I missing something here?

thx!

Answer (score 0):

> This works fine but I noticed when looping through the objects that the actual content is missing layout formatting, especially line breaks.

And *how* are you doing this “looping through”, or rather more important, how are you checking that there are no line breaks?

> or am I missing something here?

Well, you wouldn’t be the first one to forget that HTML does just display any whitespace condensed to one space character under normal circumstances …